# How to update an account field based on owner deactivation date?

Tags: account, user, field-update

I'm a bit of a newb so forgive me but am trying to figure out how to do the following:

(1) update an account custom field picklist value 30 days after an account owner is deactivated.  We have a custom field called life cycle stage.  The idea is to move this from 'customer' to 'dormant' for any account that belongs to an inactive owner for 30 days

(2) send an email to inactive account owner's manager 15 days after account owner becomes inactive if same life cycle stage field = 'prospect'.

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Todd

Answer (score 0):

you can use process builder for that, 
 1 go to setup->process builder make new process give a name, choose when record changed
2. choose object user, when record created or edited.
3.then make condition like this[image]

set schedule action
[image]
 now

Answer (score 0):

last things what you have to do change the account satge
so click add action and choose record type and in record type, choose related object account id then you will see this type of picture
[image]